# How to count JSON response and output how many lines there are

Tags: php, json, multithreading, foreach

Hello fellow developers,

I have been trying to manipulate the output and display the total amount of workers there are instead of outputting the workers name as a string.

Bellow you will find the data that i am receiving and further down i will explain how i would like to handle the JSON response.

```
{
  "result":
  {
   "addr":"ADDRESS_HERE",
   "workers":
     [
       ["worker1080",{},2,1,"200000",0,22],
       ["worker1080",{"a":"899.4"},3,1,"512",0,24]
     ],
   "algo":-1
  },
  "method":"stats.provider.workers"
 }
```

So basically as you can see from the above response that there are 2 workers named "worker1080" active on that address.

The bellow php code is how i retrieve the data and output only the names of the workers:

```html
        <?php
          $btcwallet = get_btc_addy();
          if (isset($cur_addy)) {
          $method4 = new methods();
          $worker_stats = new urls();
          $get_data = file_get_contents(utf8_encode($worker_stats->nice_url.$method4->m4.$cur_addy));
          $get_json = json_decode($get_data, true);
          foreach ($get_json['result']['workers'] as $v) {
            $i = 0;
            print $v[$i++]."<br />";
          }
        }
        ?>
```

$get_json is the variable that decodes the data from $get_data and displays the worker names and increments every time a worker is added or online. 
now i currently have 2 workers online as shown in the JSON response.

it outputs:

```
worker1080
worker1080
```

which is perfect although if i try using a foreach statement and try to display the the total amount of workers online it should display 2 instead of the names, it has to also increment for each worker that the json repsonse outputs.
EG: i have 2 workers online now, but in an hour i will connect 10 more it would display the following:

```
worker1080
worker1080
worker1070
worker1070
worker1080ti
worker1080ti
workerASIC
workerASIC
workerASIC
workerCPU
workerCPU
workerCPU
```

Now i try to use the following to display the total:

```
count($v[$i++]);
```

and i have tried using a foreach within the foreach, and both count and the foreach both will either display "0" by all the workers or "1"
bellow is an example of the output.

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

How would i go about counting each line in the output and display the total number of workers ?

Comment: The post-increment is silly. Assuming that the answers you are looking for are 2 and 10 for the 2 scenarios you describe the answer is `count($get_json['result']['workers']);`. This is a trivial issue in a relatively complex bit of code, apparently controlling a very complex piece of code.

Comment: @symcbean Thank you for your response, could you illiterate to why you would say post-increment is silly. I am new to this coding thing and trying to find the best way to get my code to perform flawlessly as well as be efficient and only use resources when needed. I have tried your fix `count($get_json['result']['workers']);` and it works which is great :)

Comment: There is no reason for incrementing $i in the loop - you reset it to zero on each iteration (otherwise you'd get the wrong result). There's no reason to incremet it in the call to count (and the count needs to applied to the array containing $v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @symcbean for the solution.

```html
<?php
          $btcwallet = get_btc_addy();
          if (isset($cur_addy)) {
          $method4 = new methods();
          $worker_stats = new urls();
          $get_data = file_get_contents(utf8_encode($worker_stats->nice_url.$method4->m4.$cur_addy));
          $get_json = json_decode($get_data, true);
          print count($get_json['result']['workers'])."<br />"; // <-- solution *removed foreach and $i incrementation as its not needed for count
        }
        ?>
```

it now displays the correct number of workers :)